# Is there any benefit to using createDocumentFragment as opposed to an out-of-DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom

AFAIK, the benefit of document fragments is that they don't cause reflow events, until the fragment is inserted into the DOM. Sounds reasonable, but it seems that out-of-DOM elements don't cause reflows either.

For example:

```
// with document fragment
var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
// append a bunch of hyperlinks to df
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.appendChild(df);
document.body.appendChild(container);

// with in-memory element

var container = document.createElement('div');
// append a bunch of hyperlinks to container
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

I ran this in Chrome and Firefox, and didn't see any performance differences between the two versions.

Given the age of the `createDocumentFragment` method (even IE6 supports it), my theory is that it was more efficient at some point, but years of optimizations to browser rendering engines have made it unnecessary. Is this correct?

Comment: Most likely this is just two ways of doing the same thing. Maybe it is more semantic if you use createDocumentFragment, but aside of that the two methods seem equal to me

Comment: I've thought about this some more, and my conclusion is that the two methods, while functionally equivalent, serve slightly purposes. The main difference between them is that the document fragment is not itself a DOM node - just a *temporary container*. This makes it the preferred choice when you want to add a bunch of elements to an existing container, without adding a new parent.

If you want a container along with your new elements, then it is better to use `createElement`. This is actually a rehash of what @Bubbles said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragments are for use when you have many elements to append to an existing element. When you just have a single element to append (along with it's children), I don't believe their is any performance difference - but if you're forced to append many to the same target, a fragment may be appropriate. John Resig set up a test for this a while back, which you can [run here](http://ejohn.org/apps/fragment/) - by all appearances, fragments still come through with better performance in the right circumstances.

His full post on the subject can be found [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/), which provides a pretty decent overview of the different performance characteristics.

Comment: The thing is that John's code compares createDcoumentFragment to in-DOM manipulation, which already know is slow. If we change the "normal" append code to use an out-of-DOM element , i.e. createElement('div'), then the performance difference disappears.

Comment: I don't agree. John creates a  list of DOM elements in the same fashion you create them - by calling createElement on document. The difference is you then attach each of these to a container div, whereas John's code individually attaches each of these. In effect, what fragment's allow is for you to structure code very similarly to the container element that you use, but without the need for a container div to enter the dom - fragments can insert multiple elements into an existing element, rather than an element containing multiple elements.

Answer (score 2):

A normal DOM insertion can only insert one node (and by extension its children, and their children, etc) all in one go.

A document fragment can contain multiple "top level" nodes which can all be added in one go, without requiring that they already share a common parent *before* they're added to the DOM.

In your example it doesn't matter, because you have that single `container` div which is the parent of all the child nodes, so "normal" DOM insertion works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Performance matters.
createDocumentFragment is out-of-dom element. Operations with it are performed faster.
So if you have  to actively manipulate with fragmemt before appending to the DOM - use createDocumentFragment.

Otherwise - no differense.